# Como executar uma lista de objeto com MERGE devolvendo os Id do insert ou Update?

Tags: c#, sql-server, lista, desempenho, dapper

Estou com o seguinte cenário; Preciso fazer um `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` de uma lista de `List<PRD_ARTIGO_VARIANTE_VALOR>`, minha duvida é se tem como eu passar a lista de uma unica vez obtendo os `Ids` do `UPDATE` ou do `INSERT` realizado.

A condição usada para `UPDATE` não é via `Id` como no código abaixo.

Da forma que esta, funciona perfeitamente, mas queria saber se tem como levar tudo de uma unica vez para o banco de dados, sem ter que usar o  `foreach (var variantesValor in variantesValores)`, igual quando fazemos um `INSERT` de uma lista com o `DAPPER`.

```
public void MergeArtigoVarianteValor(List<PRD_ARTIGO_VARIANTE_VALOR> variantesValores, SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ObterConnectionString()))
    {
        foreach (var variantesValor in variantesValores)
        {       
            string query = $@"  DECLARE @VarianteValor TABLE( ID_PRD_VARIANTE_VALOR int)
                                MERGE lx_prd.PRD_ARTIGO_VARIANTE_VALOR AS artVar  
                                USING (SELECT @ID_LINX, @ID_ARTIGO, @ID_ATRIBUTO, @ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO, @LABEL) 
                                AS source (    ID_LINX,  ID_ARTIGO,  ID_ATRIBUTO,  ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO,  LABEL)  
                                ON (artVar.ID_LINX = source.ID_LINX 
                                and artVar.ID_ARTIGO = source.ID_ARTIGO 
                                and artVar.ID_ATRIBUTO = source.ID_ATRIBUTO
                                and artVar.ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO = source.ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO)  
                                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                    UPDATE SET LABEL = source.LABEL
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
                                    INSERT (       ID_LINX,        ID_ARTIGO,        ID_ATRIBUTO,        ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO,        LABEL)  
                                    VALUES (source.ID_LINX, source.ID_ARTIGO, source.ID_ATRIBUTO, source.ID_ATRIBUTO_DEFINICAO, source.LABEL)
                                    OUTPUT inserted.ID_PRD_VARIANTE_VALOR INTO @VarianteValor;  
                                SELECT ID_PRD_VARIANTE_VALOR FROM @VarianteValor";

            variantesValor.ID_PRD_VARIANTE_VALOR = connection.Query<int>(query, variantesValor, null, true, 3600).First();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não me recordo de já ter utilizado, mas o SQL especifica o `<output_clause>`. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @tvdias, sim , mas vc sabe como passar a lista no Dapper e recuperar todos IDs no output ?

Comment: ja tentou  usar bulk insert/update  ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, O DAPPER tem isso na versão gratuita ? tipo fazer insert se não existir ou fazer update caso exista ?

Comment: Você tem o DER da tabela?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, sério que vc colocou informações sensíveis do seu BD aqui? só uma dica de segurança, você pode mascarar os campos...

Comment: @AdjairCosta, até vc sabe onde esta servidor sabe qual o banco do servidor já vai ter uma dor de cabeça. Depois ainda teria que ter acesso para vc fazer alguma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível realizar esta operação.

Caso seja inserido em uma única query SQL você poderia "confiar" que foram inseridos de forma consecutiva.

Uma opção seria a criação de um procedimento que retorne os IDs atualizados ou inseridos.